# sending content of a pipe using http

Tags: c++, http, pipe

My question is a bit long so please bare with me.
I have a c++ app that is supposed to take a command from the user, execute the command in cmd.exe and then send the result to a server using HTTP protocol.
I figured out that in order to run a command from a c++ program I need to open a pipe and then read the output of the cmd process in my code using `fgets()`.
this is my code for reading from pipe:

```
char buffer [SIZE];
//strCmd is the command to be executed in cmd
FILE* pipe = _popen(strCmd.c_str(), "r");
if (!pipe)
{
    std::cerr << "cannot open pipe" << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}
while (fgets(buffer, SIZE, pipe))
{
    std::cout << buffer;
}

_pclose(pipe);
```

now suppose I set `strCmd` as "dir".The output that I read from pipe is this:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0C5C-B0D7

 Directory of C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\pipe-demo-new\pipe-demo-new

10/05/2020  12:26 AM    <DIR>          .
10/05/2020  12:26 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/04/2020  05:08 PM    <DIR>          Debug
10/05/2020  12:26 AM             1,977 pipe-demo-new.cpp
10/04/2020  05:12 PM             8,552 pipe-demo-new.vcxproj
10/03/2020  07:43 PM             1,340 pipe-demo-new.vcxproj.filters
10/03/2020  07:43 PM             1,757 ReadMe.txt
09/06/2020  10:05 AM             1,184 selfsigned.crt
10/03/2020  07:43 PM               300 stdafx.cpp
10/03/2020  07:43 PM               320 stdafx.h
10/03/2020  07:43 PM               314 targetver.h
10/04/2020  05:12 PM    <DIR>          x64
           8 File(s)         15,744 bytes
           4 Dir(s)  13,798,125,568 bytes free
```

I use this piece of code to send the array `buffer` in a http post request to the server:

```
void SendRequest(char* buffer) {
httplib::Client cli(IP, 8000);
httplib::Params params{
    { "key", buffer }
};

auto res = cli.Post("/postReq/", params);
if (res) {
    cout << res->status << endl;
    cout << res->get_header_value("Content-Type") << endl;
    //redirect
    cli.set_follow_location(true);
    res = cli.Get("/postReq/");
   }
 }
```

But what I get in the server is this (only last line of output):

```
               4 Dir(s)  13,798,125,568 bytes free
```

I know that this behavior is expected and is just how `fgets()` works. My question is, is there anyway to get the full output there? Is there a better approach to get the output to the server?
I thought about sending the request right after calling `fgets()` (inside while loop) but that will send the string in multiple pieces and is no use in my case cause I want to have the string as only one record in my database.
I am using Visual Studio 2017 on windows 10 and the server is running on my localhost.
Server is written using django.
Don't know if it matters but I am using cpp-httplib for sending http request.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, this is not "how fgets() works". It's how ***your program*** works. It reads each line from the pipe into the same buffer, in a loop. So, in the end the buffer is left with the last line read. If you'd like your program to collect the entire output from the pipe, to collect each line read into a single buffer, you'll simply need to change your program's logic accordingly. This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with http, but with the logic you use to read the output from the pipe.

Comment: @samVarshavchik Thank you for answering my question.Well I know that I need to change the logic I just dont know how.I am new to this issue.The problem is that thre command is not always "dir" it could be anything and so I dont know the size of output therefore I cant allocate a buffer larg enough to store the output all at once.So I thought of a small buffer that will read the pipe untill its empty.What else do you suggest I try?

Comment: You should try what you already know. In the above code there's some mysterious object called "`strCmd`" whose `c_str()` gets called. This must be a `std::string`, so the above shows that you are aware of the existence of `std::string`. You must also be aware that there is no upper limit on the size of a `std::string`, and `std::string` conveniently manages all the memory for you, it can get bigger or smaller, and you can make the `std::string` bigger, automatically, simply by adding more text to it. So? What exactly is unclear to you?